# Regex for strictly matching the percentage values

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to strictly match the strings like `45%` or `2%`.

It should not match if there are other strings added before or after the required string like `abc34%` or `34%cd212`.

Comment: @anubhava: Only if it's acceptable to match `24%` in the string `foo-24%`.

Comment: What about `0.000039000%` ?

Comment: @sin floating points should be allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```js
const testData = (data) => /^(?:[1-9]\d?%|0%)$/.test(data)

const test = ["1.2%","120%","12%","2%", "ABc%", "1,3%", "23", "abc34%", "34%cd212", "00%", "0%"]

for(let x of test){
  console.log(`${x} ${testData(x)}`)
}
```

`^` begining of string
`[1-9]` number from 1 to 9
`\d?` optional 1 number
`%` % symbol
`$` end of sting
`|0%` or 0%

Comment: @MaciejKocieja "00%" should be avoided

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted, 0% is fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\d+%$
```

- `^` Start of the string. This makes sure, that the string `ABC45%` is not allowed.
- `\d+` At least one number
- `$` End of the string. This makes sure, that the string `45%ABC` is not allowed

**Here is a live example:**

```js
var regex = /^\d+%$/;
var samples = [
  "123%",
  "ABC12%",
  "ABC123%ABC",
  "123%abc",
  "abc"
];

for(var i=0; i<samples.length; i++) {
  var sample = samples[i];
  console.log(sample, !!sample.match(regex));
}
```